# python - store all paths from source to destination in recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, recursion, depth-first-search

I want store all paths in list for further processing(create JSON output) but the list where routes are appended are at the and empty. It is possible somehow manage it?
The code is based on DFS algorithm(source modified - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/)

```
from collections import defaultdict 

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)
        self.all_path = []

    def add_edge(self,u, v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)


    def get_paths(self, u, destination, visited, path):
        path.append(u)
        visited.append(u)

        if u == destination:
            self.all_path.append(path)
            print(path)

        else:
            for i in self.graph[u]:
                if i not in visited:
                    self.get_paths(i, destination, visited, path)
        path.pop()
        visited.pop()


    def set_vars(self, origin, destination):
        path = []
        visited = []
        self.get_paths(origin, destination, visited, path)


g = Graph()
g.add_edge('BA', 'NR')
g.add_edge('BA', 'VK')
g.add_edge('BA', 'NZ')
g.add_edge('VK', 'BA')
g.add_edge('VK', 'NR')
g.add_edge('NR', 'NZ')
g.add_edge('VK', 'BA')
g.add_edge('BA', 'NR')
g.add_edge('BA', 'VK')
g.add_edge('VK', 'NR')


g.set_vars('BA','NR')
print(g.all_path)


output:
['BA', 'NR']
['BA', 'VK', 'NR']
['BA', 'VK', 'NR']
['BA', 'NR']
['BA', 'VK', 'NR']
['BA', 'VK', 'NR']
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: If you're not really interested in writing the graph algorithms yourself, I'd recommend looking at the `networkx` library...

Comment: In your entire processing, you only create one `path` list object.  You pass it around and manipulate it, but it's always the same object.  You save a bunch of references to it in `self.all_path`, but by the time `get_paths` finishes, that list object is empty, and so you print that empty list 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't append six different paths: you appended a reference to your reused `path` list, six different times.  Simply tracing `all_path` illustrates the problem nicely.
When you reuse `path` on each backtrack, you overwrite the prior value.  When you clear it to the null list at the end, you destroy even that last path.

Instead, append a copy of the list:

```
        self.all_path.append(path[:])
```

This gives you all six terminal paths -- two copies of one, and four of the other, in keeping with your algorithm.